# A statistical function that compiles a curve to a number?

Tags: r

My title reads itself...If that's even what that means. Forget it.

I need to compare some data curves over time for each of the 50 states and see which state is the closest to say, New York. I am using R, and have some reproducible code and equations. For the example given below, how would I figure out that, y1 is "closer" to y2 than y3 by consolidating each to a single number?

Thanks in advance,
A new guy

**EDIT:**
When I say closest, I mean the smallest difference of values.
I was just thinking mean value, but I would like something more..*statistically accurate*
$$x = 1,2,3...10   $$
$$y1 = 2x + 3$$
$$y2 = 3x + 2$$
$$y3 = 5x - 17$$

````
x = 1:10
y1 = 2*x + 3
y2 = 3*x + 2
y3 = 5*x - 17```
````

Comment: Welcome to CV. There are infinitely many ways to answer this, in much the same sense that you would get many different answers to a vague question like "how do I tell which of my family members I am closest to?"  Would that mean in distance as the crow flies, in travel time, in age, or emotionally, for instance?  Likewise, we cannot give you a definite answer until you explain what "closest" *means* to you.  You can do that in an edit to your question.

Comment: Does what I did work?? I'm sorry for being vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean squared error and mean absolute error come to mind. Loosely speaking, the former is kind of like variance, and the latter is a modification of the former.

Let’s look at the equations comparing $y_1$ and $y_2$:

$$MSE_{1,2} =\dfrac{\sum_{x=1}^{10} \big(y_{1}(x)-y_{2}(x)\big)^2}{n}$$

$$MAE_{1,2} =\dfrac{\sum_{x=1}^{10} \big\vert y_{1}(x)-y_{2}(x)\big\vert}{n}$$

What MSE means is that you find the difference between the at each value of $x$, square that quantity, add up all 10, and then divide by 10. (See why it’s called mean squared error?) MAE is similar but uses absolute values of differences instead of squaring.

MAE is less sensitive to extreme differences than MSE. Depending on your problem, that may be very desirable or very undesirable. MSE would be the common way to go, however. MSE is quite tied to numerous nice concepts in statistics (variance being one of them).

MSE and MAE have different units; MSE is in squares units, while MAE is in the original units (think kg$^{\text{2}}$ vs kg). To get MSE in the original units, it is common to take the square root at the end, resulting in root mean squared error.

$$RMSE=\sqrt{MSE}$$

If RMSE reminds you of standard deviation, it’s similar, yes.

Please do note, however, that this gives a one-number summary for the difference between two curves; it does not condense a curve into one number. However, I think you want to summarize the difference as one number.

Comment: Hi Dave, 

This is awesome! I will definitely use MSE! Though you are right, I wanted 1 curve as one number, not the difference.

Any ideas? Or possibly any substitutes?